# Making HTTP post request (with an input type="file") from within Maven, using command line parameters if possible

Tags: http, maven-2, post, multipartform-data

I would like to convert this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! [ $# == 2 ]; then
   echo Usage: update-module admin-password module-file
   exit 1
fi
if ! [ -f $2 ]; then
   echo Error: module file $2 does not exist
   exit 1
fi
curl -c /tmp/cookie.txt -d uname=admin -d pw=${1} http://localhost:8080/openmrs/loginServlet
curl -b /tmp/cookie.txt -F action=upload -F update=true -F moduleFile=\@$2 http://localhost:8080/openmrs/admin/modules/module.list
rm -rf /tmp/cookie.txt > /dev/null 2>&1
```

into something that could be placed into a maven pom.xml file.

Note that module-file is a jar file (renamed .omod), admin-password would ideally be specified on the command line, similar to command line parameters to maven archetype:create
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html#Alternative_way_to_start_creating_your_Archetype

(the hostname should ideally be specified on the command line too).

Thank you

Yours
Misha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [GMaven](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/) to [embed an inline Groovy Script](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code#ExecutingGroovyCode-ExecuteanInlineGroovyScript), and use [apache httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/) to implement the post request. Something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source><![CDATA[

                    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
                    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
                    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
                    import org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity;
                    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

                    String url = pom.properties['http.url'];
                    File file = new File(pom.properties['http.attachmentFile'])
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
                    InputStreamEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(file.newInputStream());
                    post.setEntity entity;
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

                ]]></source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This uses the maven properties `http.url` and `http.attachmentFile` that you can specify on the command line using the -D syntax or in a pom.xml file in a `<properties>` block. Obviously, you'd need to extend the functionality to what else your shell script is doing, but this should get you started.

Comment: I knew it! I knew you would come with a Groovy solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Exec Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/). You might want to just store the cookie in `${project.build.directory}` instead of `/tmp` (and then you don't need to remove it.

You can use any property name for the host you like, say `host.name`. You should set a default in the POM:

```
<properties>
  <host.name>...</host.name>
</properties>
```

That can be overridden with `-Dhost.name=...` on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Top voted answer updated to work for latest JDK's, had to move to gmavenplus - had a similar challenge to try to post a file from Maven, no great options I've found so far to do an easy equivalent of this;

`curl <url> --data-binary '@filename'`

```
<plugin>


            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                    <version>4.5.13</version>
                </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                      <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
                      <!-- any version of Groovy \>= 1.5.0 should work here -->
                      <version>3.0.9</version>
                      <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>


            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <scripts>
                            <script><![CDATA[
        
                            import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
                            import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
                            import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
                            import org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity;
                            import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
                            import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
                            import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
                            import java.io.File;
        
                            String url = 'https://kroki.io/plantuml/svg';
                            
                            def file = new File("${http.attachmentFile}");
                            
                            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
                            InputStreamEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(file.newInputStream());
                            post.setEntity(entity);
                            
                            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                        
                            
                            println "Status: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();  
                            println "Response " + response.toString();

                            ]]></script></scripts>
                    </configuration>

                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
```