# Send HTTP DELETE from maven

Tags: maven

Is there a plugin to send HTTP requests, specifically DELETE with payloads, from maven?

ps. As possible options I have already considered, exec+curl, exec of a java program, a custom plugin, but I am mostly interested of a ready/tested plugin

Comment: Note DELETE should not define body semantics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request

Comment: You might just use the Groovy plugin, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3776965/2169091